# How to import ".off" object file using python code

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, import, file-format

I have installed import_off addon from this [github repo](https://github.com/alextsui05/blender-off-addon). This addon provide import functionality of the ".off" file in blender using the GUI. But there is no way I can import ".off" file using python.

Please tell if there is any way I can import .off files using python, since I intend to work on many 3D models and using GUI is not possible on all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are under a misapprehension that you can not use the [import OFF addon](https://github.com/alextsui05/blender-off-addon) you posted.

Get the name of the operator by mousing over the import menu `bpy.ops.import_mesh.off(...)`

Typing the operator in the python console and using autocomplete <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> exposes the parameters (Same as those in the UI).

```
bpy.ops.import_mesh.off(filepath="", filter_glob="*.off", axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')
>>> bpy.ops.import_mesh.off(
```

Simply pass the filepath of an OFF file to the operator in your own code.

Eg: to import with default settings.

```
filepath = "some/path/to/file.off"
bpy.ops.import_mesh.off(filepath=filepath)
```

This can be done for pretty much all import / export addons.

Comment: What does "axis_forward='Y'" mean?

Comment: To define a 3d space used by an application, need which axis is up, for blender z, and which axis points towards you (y) in front ortho.  A lot of other applications use y up. Without converting a blender model will be exported with the wrong alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @batFINGER worked for me, but I had to pass the parameters as named parameters.

Do it like this:

```
bpy.ops.import_mesh.off(filepath = filepath)
```

Not like this:

```
bpy.ops.import_mesh.off(filepath)
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed the oversight in my answer.  In future suggest adding a comment or making an edit.